# Put in a First name from a list using a pulled username

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-rules

I have my form so that when it loads it pulls the username of the user viewing the form but I want it to grab the associated first name from a list I have on the site.

I've gotten it so that it puts in the username for the Value on a dropdown and the Displayname is the firstname but whenever the form is saved it saves the username and not the first name to the list

Answer (score 0):

If the field is a person field, then the whole person field with all its information will be saved. If you only want to save part of the person information you need a text field and use InfoPath rules to set the text field value to the first name before saving the form.

Comment: it's not a person field, they are only text boxes and a drop down that is connected to a list of usernames and firstnames

Comment: Well, use InfoPath rules to populate the text box and save the form. What you see in the text box will be saved. I'm not quite sure I understand what the problem is. You may want to edit your question and add more detail about what you want to achieve and what you are struggling with.